# Is there has a smart way to compute the 1 order derivative of the circle equation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have encountered a compute problem.

This exercise has given the circle equation and a para-curve equation with unknown parameters, the para-curve and circle has the same radius of curvature, and compute the three parameters. I know it has easier way than plain way to compute the derivative, but I don't know the exactly step.
$$ \left( x - \frac 12 \right)^2 + \left( y- \frac 52 \right)^2 = \frac 12 $$

I want to know the smart way to compute the 1order derivative of this circle equation.

Comment: /What does "1order" mean? Do you mean first order derivative?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I mean y', not y''. Sorry about the misunderstanding, I'm Chinese.

Comment: You should state in which context did problem did appear, and what you did try.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sorry about that I didn't state my question clearly. This exercise has given the circle equation and a para-curve equation with  unknown parameters, the para-curve and circle has the same radius of curvature, and compute the three parameters. I know it has easier  way  than plain way to compute the derivative, but I don't know the exactly step. So I post it here.

Comment: You should state this information as an edit to the question, not only as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=a + r \cos(t)$ and $y = b+ r\sin(t)$. We have
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \dfrac{\cos(t)}{-\sin(t)} = - \cot(t) = -\dfrac{x-a}{y-b}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to consider implicit differentiation of $$F=\left( x - \frac 12 \right)^2 + \left( y- \frac 52 \right)^2 - \frac 12=0$$ So $$F'_x=2x-1$$ $$F'_y=2y-5$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=-\frac{2x-1}{2y-5}$$